# How to get all particular weekDays between two date objects in momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I get all weekDays(a particular weekday concerned) between a start Date and an end date inclusively. The function would take startDate, endDate (both as moment objects), dayNum(as integer)(0 - Sun, 1 - Mon ... 6 - Sat) and return a list of moment objects of such days.

I have written a function but it is not working.

```
const getDates = (startDate, endDate, dayNum) => {
let realStart = moment(startDate);
let end = moment(endDate);
let start = realStart.clone();
start.add(-15, "days");

let result = [];


var current = start.clone();
current.day(dayNum + 1);

  while (current.isSameOrBefore(end)) {
    if (current.isSameOrAfter(realStart)) {
      let temp = current.clone();
      result.push(temp);
      current.day(8 + dayNum);
    } else {
      current.day(8 + dayNum);
    }
  }
return result;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rzr_f's answer always increments one day at a time, which is inefficient when there is a large span between `startDate` and `endDate`, or when the function is called repeatedly.

Here is a more efficient version which increments by 7 days at a time, and never has to check whether the date it's adding is on the correct weekday since it always starts on the correct weekday:

```
const getDates = (startDate, endDate, dayNum) => {
  let current = moment(startDate)
  const end = moment(endDate)
  const results = []

  // If current is on the wrong weekday, move it forward to the first matching weekday:
  if (current.weekday() !== dayNum) {
    current.add(dayNum >= current.weekday() ? ( dayNum - current.weekday() ) : ( 7 - ( current.weekday() - dayNum ) ), 'day')
  }

  while(current.isSameOrBefore(end)) {
    results.push(current.clone())
    current.add(7, 'day')
  } 

  return results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work for what you're trying to do:

```js
const getDates = (startDate, endDate, dayNum) => {
  let current = moment(startDate)
  const end = moment(endDate)

  const results = []

  while(current.isSameOrBefore(end)) {
    if (current.weekday() === dayNum) results.push(current.clone())
    current.add(1, 'day')
  } 

  return results
}
```